# Sudoku Backtracking Non valid Sudoku

Tags: java, backtracking, sudoku

I created a Sudoku Backtracking solver and it works just fine, 
but now i want to give out an error if the sudoku cant be solved because it isnt valid
for example if this sudoku is given:

http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2241/sudokugq.jpg

what can i do to make my solving method give out an error if it isnt solveable?
I always end up with Zeros or stuck in a loop.

```
    public void solve( int row, int col ) throws Exception
   {
      // Throw an exception to stop the process if the puzzle is solved
      if( row > 8 ){
        //Gelöst
      }
      // If the cell is not empty, continue with the next cell
      if( sudo[row][col] != 0 ){
         next( row, col ) ;
        }
      else
      {
         // Find a valid number for the empty cell
         for( int num = 1; num < 10; num++ )
         {
            if( checkHorizontal(row,num) == false && checkVertikal(col,num)== false&& checkBox(row,col,num)== false )
            {
               sudo[row][col] = num ;


               // Delegate work on the next cell to a resudosive call
               next( row, col ) ;
            }
         }

         // No valid number was found, clean up and return to caller
         sudo[row][col] = 0 ;
      }

   }

   //Ruft solve für das nächste Feld auf
   public void next( int row, int col ) throws Exception
   {
      if( col < 8 )
         solve( row, col + 1 ) ;
      else
         solve( row + 1, 0 ) ;
   }
```

Comment: I found an ugly design here: `solve` depends on `next` and `next` depends on `solve`.

Comment: and what is so wrong about that?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - I have seen much more complex recursive solutions than this. Although it is complex I would argue that it is also a true implementation of a solution. Besides - `next` is just choosing the next coordinate to try.

Comment: yes, but that doesnt solve my question.
my question is: If there is a sudoku, which is not valid (like in the picture), what can i do to give out an error and get out of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely when you hit the `sudo[row][col] = 0 ;` code you have just finished trying every value in a square and found no solution with any of them. Surely that is the point where you decide to give up with a no-solution state.

Thinking about it further - I suspect I am only nearly right. If you hit this code **and** this is the **first** cell you are trying (i.e. the first empty cell you found) then that is your fail moment.

BTW - I'm not sure it would be a good idea to use an Exception to indicate a solution as you suggest in your comment.

---

This now correctly rejects the board you posted - notice that not only are there two "3"s on the first row there are also two "5"s in the first column. This code seems to work for me now. Perhaps you could try it on an insoluble one.

```
public class Test {

    static final int S = 9;
    int[][] sudo;

    public Test() {
        // Just leave it empty.
        sudo = new int[S][S];
    }

    public Test(int[][] sudo) {
        this.sudo = sudo;
    }

    // This number should not appear anywhere in the row.
    public boolean checkHorizontal(int row, int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
            if (sudo[row][i] == num) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // This number should not appear anywhere in the col.
    public boolean checkVertical(int col, int num) {
        for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
            if (sudo[i][col] == num) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // This number should not appear anywhere in the box.
    private boolean checkBox(int row, int col, int num) {
        // Round down to nearest 3.
        int r = (row / 3) * 3;
        int c = (col / 3) * 3;
        for (int i = r; i < r + 3; i++) {
            for (int j = c; j < c + 3; j++) {
                if (sudo[i][j] == num) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    boolean check(int row, int col, int num) {
        // All checks must pass.
        return checkHorizontal(row, num)
                && checkVertical(col, num)
                && checkBox(row, col, num);
    }

    public boolean solve(int row, int col) {
        // Got to the end?
        if (row >= S) {
            //Gelöst
            return true;
        }
        // If the cell is empty
        if (sudo[row][col] == 0) {
            // Find a valid number for the empty cell
            for (int num = 1; num < 10; num++) {
                // Can this number be put there?
                if (check(row, col, num)) {
                    // Yes!
                    sudo[row][col] = num;
                    // Try that.
                    if (next(row, col)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Clean up.
            sudo[row][col] = 0;
        } else {
            // Move on.
            if (next(row, col)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // Failed to find a solution.
        return false;
    }

    //Ruft solve für das nächste Feld auf
    public boolean next(int row, int col) {
        if (col < S - 1) {
            // Step right.
            return solve(row, col + 1);
        } else {
            // Step down.
            return solve(row + 1, 0);
        }
    }

    public boolean boardOk() {
        // Initial test to ensure it is a valid array.
        // Must have that many rows.
        boolean ok = sudo.length == S;
        for (int row = 0; ok && row < S; row++) {
            // Each row must be that long.
            ok &= sudo[row].length == S;
            for (int col = 0; ok && col < S; col++) {
                // Each filled square must be valid.
                if (sudo[row][col] != 0) {
                    int num = sudo[row][col];
                    // Remove it.
                    sudo[row][col] = 0;
                    // Check it can be added.
                    ok &= check(row, col, num);
                    // Put it back.
                    sudo[row][col] = num;
                }
            }
        }
        return ok;
    }

    void solve() {

        if (boardOk()) {
            boolean solved = solve(0, 0);
            if (solved) {
                System.out.println("Solved!");
                print();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Insoluble!");
            print();
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < sudo.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sudo[i]));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().solve();
        int[][] test = {
            {0, 0, 6, 5, 8, 3, 3, 2, 7},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 5, 0},
            {5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3},
            {0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 9, 2, 0, 3, 0, 6},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
            {3, 4, 2, 0, 0, 6, 9, 1, 5},
            {5, 0, 5, 4, 0, 9, 0, 3, 2},
            {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4},};
        new Test(test).solve();
    }
}
```

Comment: no, sudo[row][col] = 0 ; just indicates that it goes a step backwards

Comment: i dont understand what you mean with "and this is the first cell you are trying" 
Could you explain that?
sorry if it sounds stupid, english is not my mother tongue

Comment: Not stupid - Give me a few minutes - I'm trying something. :)

Comment: you missed one 3 in your sudoku board, with one three it is no problem, because its valid.
But with 2 3s in one row it isnt valid, so it CANT work

Comment: Edited the code - please retry - in fact there were two problems with the board you posted. There are also two "5"s in the first column.

Comment: this version really works just fine, now i only have to implement it to my code :) thank you very much, i appreciate it

Comment: My code solves an empty board and the board you posted (without the extra "3" and "5"). In your code you need to follow my lead with returning true/false for solved/unsolved. Implement that and the extra validity check and you should be done. Do NOT be tempted to throw an `Exception`, that is **lazy**.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon its a really nice way to solve sudoku. But how do I put a check if the puzzle has multiple solution??

Comment: @Divyanshu - You would have to modify the `solve` method to try all numbers rather than just stop on the first solution. This would make the algorithm take a VERY long time as there are up to 10^81 possible solutions to check.