# Sudoku Block Checker Java

Tags: java, runtime-error, sudoku

I'm building a Sudoku checker and I've made a row checker and a column checker. I'm currently trying to make a block checker (3x3 block). Any insight on this would be great.

```
public boolean checkBlock (int col0to2, int row0to2)
 {
   int [] tempArray = new int [3];
   for (int x=0; x<3; x++)
   {
     for (int y=0; y<3;y++)
      {
        if ((board [col0to2+x][row0to2+y]) > 0 && (board [col0to2+x][row0to2+y]) < 10)
        {
          int tempVal = board [col0to2+x][row0to2+y];
          tempArray [tempVal - 1] = tempVal; // i think this line is giving me the run 
                                            // error   
    }
  } 
}
 return true;
}
```

Comment: if you have a row check function, and a col check function then just loop on those

Comment: There's a block checker here (along with the others) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15124194/823393).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 9 possible values, so your array should be size `9`, not `3`

You only need to count if the cell has been filled already. If it has, then return false. If you make it to the end without returning false, return true.

`++` makes the returned value be incremented so you can compare it. If it's 2, then the cell has been incremented already.

### Code:

```
public class BlockTest {
  public static boolean checkBlock (int col0to2, int row0to2)
  {
    int [] tempArray = new int[9];
    for (int x=0; x<3; x++)
    {
      for (int y=0; y<3;y++)
      {
        int tempVal = board [col0to2+x][row0to2+y];
        if (tempVal < 1 || tempVal > 9) return false;
        if (++tempArray[tempVal - 1] == 2) return false;
      } 
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static int[][] board = new int[9][9];
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        board[i][j] = i*3 + j + 1;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(checkBlock(0,0));
    board[0][0] = 7;
    System.out.println(checkBlock(0,0));
  }
}
```

### Output:

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((board [col0to2+x][row0to2+y]) > 0 && (board [col0to2+x][row0to2+y]) < 10) {
      int tempVal = board [col0to2+x][row0to2+y];
      tempArray [tempVal - 1] = tempVal; // i think this line is giving me the run error

}
```

Your bounds checks for tempval is that it should be 1 to 9 inclusive.  Suppose it is 9.  Then you are assigning tempArray[8] = 9.  You run into an issue there since tempArray was initialized as an array that holds 3 elements.

I think you want something like:

`tempArray = new int[9]`

and the assignment to be

`tempArray[x*3 + y] = tempVal`;

I didn't test that though, but basically it fills up the array with each number it finds.

Comment: oh okay i see what you mean, thanks a lot! I'll try that out!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to deal with numbers 1-9, you need room for 9 integers in `tempArray`, but you are declaring it to be only 3 long. Also, you aren't really checking that all numbers are used (and none duplicated).

```
public boolean checkBlock (int col0to2, int row0to2) {
   int [] tempArray = new int [9];
   for (int x=0; x<3; x++) {
      for (int y=0; y<3;y++) {
         int tempVal = board [col0to2+x][row0to2+y];
         if (tempVal > 0 && tempVal < 10) {
            if (tempArray[tempVal - 1] != 0) {
               return false;
            }
            tempArray [tempVal - 1] = tempVal;
         }
      } 
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see where you're coming from with this, but as other people have said your tempArray needs to be able to contain 9 values. I've written a Sudoku checker before (uni assignment, solution checking was correct, got over a mark of 90% for the whole sudoku app) and my preference was to have an array with 9 values, each representing the 1-9 digitals, but rather than setting the value to tempVal, I incremented it. Makes checking you only got one of each number easier.

```
int [] boxCounts = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

// X loop
    // y loop
        // get value
        boxCounts[value - 1]++;
    // end y loop
// end x loop

// check we found one of each
for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    if(boxCounts[j] != 1 )
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting! I'll try that out as well! thank you :) I've been sitting here for hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out for my assignment. I'd post my full checker, but it's one of those things that is good for the brain to work through to reach your own solution.

Comment: of course, I wouldnt want to whole answer because that would be cheating! The only way to learn is to practise!

Comment: Ah good, a sensible learner! I swear lots of people come on here expecting people to give them the solution so they don't have to work it out for themselves! Good luck with the rest of your coding on this :)